# Building WYSIWYG editor: Get HTML tags to go in a newline in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, tags, rich-text-editor

I built a very simple WYSIWYG editor using the classic method: an iframe in the foreground with designMode = 'on' and a textarea in the background containing the HTML code.
Everything is working fine.
The only thing i cannot achieve is to have HTML tags on newline. See example

```
first line (PRESS ENTER)
second line (PRESS ENTER)
first item list
second item list (MAKE AN UNORDERED LIST)
```

The "visual" result is

```
first line
second line
- first item list
- second item list
```

The "source code" result is

```
<div>first line</div><div>second line</div><ul><li>first item list</li><li>second item list</li></ul>
```

As you can see HTML tags are all stuck together and you can hardly read them. I would like to get this result

```
<div>first line</div>
<div>second line</div>
<ul>
<li>first item list</li>
<li>second item list</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to replace tag "on writing": through a listener on keypress/keydown event, but you must perform replace on every tag the user could write, so i don't like such solution that much.
I tried to replace tag "on reading": every time i synchronize iframe with textarea, replace a tag with tag/n, but in this way i keep adding newline between tags on every synchronization.

I'm looking for an elegant and easy-to-maintain solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to beautify the source code? https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify. The linked library can beautify JavaScript, CSS and HTML.

Comment: Great solution! It's perfect, thanks a lot